# Does the set of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself form any kind of nice space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am trying to analyze the set of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself.  I am wondering if this set has any kind of useful structure.  For instance, is it a vector space?  Is it a topological space?  Is it a metric space?

Comment: The cardinality is too big for it to be both separable and hausdorff. So there's one limitation.

Comment: It is a vector space and a ring in a consistent way, forming an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but since you mentioned _all_ real valued functions, I am tempted to refer you to these two interesting question on mathoverflow: [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/309019) and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/309158)

Comment: Any set is a metric space under some metric, the discrete metric being one such.